# How do i change the position of TablePagination component react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

React Material `TablePagination` is one component with multiple sub elements like `Rows per Page` and `Pages`

`TablePagination` is single component

```
  <TablePagination
          component="Box"
          count={10}
          onChangePage={handlePageChange}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={handleLimitChange}
          page={4}
          rowsPerPage={limit}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
        />
```

since this renders both `Rows per Page` and `Pages` how do i change `Rows per Page` position to left side and `Pages` to right side ?

I did try simply adding this, but it renders `NaN-NaN of undefined < >` after the `Rows per page` section.

```
<TablePagination rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 50, { value: -1, label: 'All' }]} />
```

Comment: Change the [css rule](https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/#css) which connected to those two. If you still can not do that and this is so important, change the order with JS in `ComponentDidMount`

Comment: @Eldshe i'm using functional components

Comment: Then use `useEffect()` which is equivalent to `componenDidMount`